# Injection of stateless session bean into custom JsonDeserializer fails

Tags: java, json, jackson, cdi

I am building an application providing a JAX-RS REST service using JPA (EclipseLink). When exposing User entities over JSON, I am using the `@XmlTransient` annotation on some fields (e.g. the password field) to hide them from the JSON representation. When sending a create or update (POST/PUT) operation, I would like to populate the missing fields again so JPA will correctly perform the operation.

My current approach is that I have a custom `JsonDeserializer` that is used to deserialize the User and to add the missing fields. For this I would like to inject (using `@Inject`) a `UserFacadeREST` bean which handles the JPA-stuff. However, this injection fails and the bean instance is `null` (which then of course causes a `NullPointerException`).

My `UserFacadeREST` bean is annoted as follows:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path(UserFacadeREST.PATH)
public class UserFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<User> {
    //...
}
```

My `UserDeserilizer` (custom `JsonDeserializer`):

```
public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

  @Inject
  private UserFacadeREST userFacade;

  @Override
  public User deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException,
      JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
    int userId = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("userID")).numberValue();
    System.out.println(userId);
    User user = userFacade.find(userId); // This line produces the NullPointerException
    return user;
  }

}
```

which I then use on my User entity with `@JsonDeserialize`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@XmlRootElement
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
public class User implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

I have included a bean.xml file in my WEB-INF folder with `bean-discovery-mode` set to `all`. What am I missing?

Comment: You can only @Inject into CDI container managed objects.  Since `UserDeserializer` is not declared to be a managed bean, no dependency injection should occur since the container wouldn't be providing this service for you.

Comment: Thanks. So how do I declare my UserDeserializer to be a managed bean? I tried with `@ApplicationScoped` and `@Singleton`, but neither one worked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jon Peterson pointed me to the right direction. I finally chose to implement the 'hackish' solution, in a way. Please note that there are basically 2 options here (if you know another one, please let me know!). Short version:

1. **Hackish solution** (the solution I chose): inject a bean programmatically using `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current().select(UserFacadeRest.class).get()` as described in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24852542/3893569) of the question mentioned by Jon or
2. **Better (clean) solution** (but also more elaborate): Redesign the logic to fill the missing fields *after* deserialization as suggested by Jon.

So for my question, the solution looks as follows:

1.

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;

public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

  private final UserFacadeREST userFacade =
      CDI.current().select(UserFacadeREST.class).get();

  // Rest as before
}
```

2. In this case, in the `deserialize` method of my `JsonDeserializer` I would construct a User that just holds the userID. In every request method I would then have to examine all the users and replace them by the actual user by calling `EntityManager.find(User.class, user.getUserID())`. This means more effort in the business logic as you have to keep in mind that everytime you need to work on a `User` in a request method, you first have to do a query to get the 'full' `User` object. In the first solution, this query is hidden from the business logic and already happens in the `JsonDeserializer`.

```
public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

  @Override
  public User deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException,
      JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
    int userId = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("userID")).numberValue();
    return new User(userId); // Placeholder User object containing only the user ID, needs to be replaced in business logic
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with CDI, but some quick Google'ing leads me to believe that `bean-discovery-mode` should either be `all`, `annotated`, or `none` (`true` not being a valid value). [Reference](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/when_your_di_breaks_bean)

If that doesn't fix it, it might be the same issue that Spring would have: you have to declare your `UserDeserializer` as a bean for the dependency injection to be applied.

EDIT: Just found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101708/cdi-injecton-not-resolved-inside-a-jackson-serializer) that is basically the same issue you are having.

Ultimately, you probably need to just redesign the logic to call `userFacade` after deserialization.

Comment: Sorry Jon, you are absolutely right. I actually used `all`, just confused it when writing the question. I just checked and the project is not even compiling when using `true`.
So how do I declare my `UserDeserializer` as a bean? Of course with some kind of annotation, but which one?

Comment: After giving this a second though, I actually don't think this can be done at all.  Instances of `UserDeserializer` are going to be created by Jackson and not by CDI.  This means that CDI annotations (ex `@Inject`) aren't going be handled.  I just found another question that I am going to put in my edited answer:

Comment: Thanks Jon, you pointed me to the right direction. Injecting an instance of UserFacadeREST programmatically works for me, so I chose this approach as it requires less effort and we have the 'refill' of the missing fields in one place and abstracted away from the business logic. But I understand, that this is not the best way. I tried to highlight this in my answer and to mention both approaches, so I will mark mine as the accepted one, just in case anybody else prefers to stick with injection.