# Obtain CDI proxy of JPA entity at runtime

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor

I have a JPA entity like this:

```
@SomeCDIInterceptorBinding
@Entity
public class Foo { ... }
```

Obviously the interceptor doesn't work, since JPA returns an entity instance and not the appropriate CDI proxy. So how do I get an instance of a CDI proxy of my entity, so that method calls invoke my interceptor?

This is specifically a 'how' question. There are other ways to solve my problem, but I want to know whether and how this specific thing is possible.

Answers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled over this post: It can be done quite simply via:

```
Foo cdiProxy = CDI.current().select(Foo.class).get();
```

Compare: [How to programmatically inject a Java CDI managed bean into a local variable in a (static) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798529/how-to-programmatically-inject-a-java-cdi-managed-bean-into-a-local-variable-in)

This way also the interceptor will work.
However (important drawback): *You manually need to clone the entity's content two times*: First on creation and a second time before persiting - as JPA can (to my understanding) not persist CDI proxies.

This, by the way is the reason I found this post. I wonder if there is any way to create 'persistable' CDI proxies. This would make the entity interception work like a charm. And why could't JPA persist CDI proxies anyhow? They should be 'fully transparent'...

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because the entities are managed by the JPA implementation like Hibernate and not by CDI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the `Managed`-State of a JPA-Bean with a technical detail of the JPA-Implementation. Entities can be created using `new`. That means they can not be proxied. So new entities are initially unmanaged. To make them managed, you can use `EntityManager.persist` or `EntityManager.merge`, but that also does not mean, that the bean is proxied. It just means that the bean is known (normally by it's Primary Key) to the JPA-Context. If you change a managed entity, these changes will be persisted at the end of the current transaction without further handling.

Proxies you will probably encounter when you look at reference- or collection-fields of entitybeans. They help with lazy-loading and keeping track of changes during a transaction.