# Get a CDI bean dynamically, NOT by injection

Tags: spring, cdi, java-ee-7

Inside of my method I want to get a CDI bean, but I don't want to use *@Inject* as I don't need this bean to be saved on instance level.
I just want to get the instance and pass it to some other method.

Previously I was working with Spring, but now switch to JEE application.
In Spring inside of my method I could simply write:

```
MyClass myClass = applicationContext.getBean(MyClass.class)
```

Is there a way to do something like this in JEE application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[How to programmatically inject a Java CDI managed bean into a local variable in a (static) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798529/how-to-programmatically-inject-a-java-cdi-managed-bean-into-a-local-variable-in)

Need to use:

```
javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current().select(C.class).get()
```

Comment: No need to answer if there is a duplicate.